# How to get saved image file path in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

Hi I am developing an app in which there is an option to pick the photos from iOS photo gallery. I have to upload the selected photos into the server. To upload the images i am using **Kaltura SDK** so i am in the situation not able to directly send the `UIImage` to server. i need to send saved image **file path**.

For that I found an solution, That is saving the selected photos in a particular file path then i will use that file path. But the problem is i do not wish to save photos again in phone memory because those photos are already stored in a particular path.

So Is there any other option to retrive the saved image file path without saving it again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one:

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    } 
}

- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"test.png" ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [self sendAction:path];
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response this is what i have done currently, here we are storing the image once again in a particular file path my question is there any option to get the path instead of storing it

Comment: Is there an option to delete that path after send it to server?

Comment: @Mutawe:can you tell me how to delete image from same path??
for this +1

Comment: What does it mean "test.png"?

Comment: That's mean that you can name it whatever you want @LKM